# Send email reminder by using If ElseIf statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below code sends an email reminder by using If and ElseIf statements in VBA. The receiver will receive an email notification of the item is either due for testing or visual inspection. The code will calculate the remaining days of the due date example 30 days. VBA will generate an email and forward to the receiver automatically and indicate yes or true on each line when there is an item due date met 30 days. But there is a bug (Else without If) in the code. Kindly advise how to debug it. Thank you.

```
           Sub datesexcelvba()
           Dim Outlook As Object, EMail As Object
           Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
           Set EMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
           Dim mydate1 As Date
           Dim mydate2 As Long
 
           Dim mydate3 As Date
           Dim mydate4 As Long
           Dim datetoday1 As Date
           Dim datetoday2 As Long
           Dim datetoday3 As Date
           Dim datetoday4 As Long
           Dim x As Long

           Lastrow = Sheets("Lift equipment1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
           For x = 3 To Lastrow
           mydate1 = Cells(x, 16).Value
           mydate3 = Cells(x, 11).Value
           mydate2 = mydate1
           mydate4 = mydate3
           Cells(x, 21).Value = mydate2
           Cells(x, 25).Value = mydate4
           datetoday1 = Date
           datetoday2 = datetoday1
           datetoday3 = Date
           datetoday4 = datetoday3
           Cells(x, 22).Value = datetoday2
           Cells(x, 26).Value = datetoday4

           If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 30 Then
           EMail.To = Cells(x, 20).Value

           With EMail
           .Subject = Cells(x, 18).Value
           .Body = Cells(x, 18).Value
           .Display
           '.Send

           ElseIf mydate4 - datetoday4 = 30 Then
           EMail.To = Cells(x, 20).Value

           With EMail
           .Subject = Cells(x, 19).Value
           .Body = Cells(x, 19).Value
           .Display
           '.Send


           Else
           End If
           End With

           Cells(x, 23) = "Yes"
           Cells(x, 23).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
           Cells(x, 24).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2

           Cells(x, 27) = "True"
           Cells(x, 27).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
           Cells(x, 28).Value = mydate4 - datetoday2
           End If
           Next
           Set EMail = Nothing
           Set Outlook = Nothing
           End Sub
```

Comment: Use indenting for each `For`, `If` and `With` then you will see that sth went wrong with your code. Search for "vba best practice indentation", e.g. https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-indentation-auto-indent/

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code would be easier to see if you correctly indented your code (as in the below).

While the below code compiles, I cannot say it matches your intent for the code (you need to test it and check) PLUS for sure the 'If' statement in the line `If True Then ' this 'If' was missing and needs to be fixed` needs fixing as it is missing from the code you posted.

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
    Dim Outlook As Object, EMail As Object
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    Dim mydate1 As Date
    Dim mydate2 As Long

    Dim mydate3 As Date
    Dim mydate4 As Long
    Dim datetoday1 As Date
    Dim datetoday2 As Long
    Dim datetoday3 As Date
    Dim datetoday4 As Long
    Dim x As Long

    lastRow = Sheets("Lift equipment1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    For x = 3 To lastRow
        mydate1 = Cells(x, 16).Value
        mydate3 = Cells(x, 11).Value
        mydate2 = mydate1
        mydate4 = mydate3
        Cells(x, 21).Value = mydate2
        Cells(x, 25).Value = mydate4
        datetoday1 = Date
        datetoday2 = datetoday1
        datetoday3 = Date
        datetoday4 = datetoday3
        Cells(x, 22).Value = datetoday2
        Cells(x, 26).Value = datetoday4
    
        If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 30 Then
            EMail.To = Cells(x, 20).Value
        
            With EMail
                If True Then ' this 'If' was missing and needs to be fixed
                    .Subject = Cells(x, 18).Value
                    .Body = Cells(x, 18).Value
                    .Display
                    '.Send
                
                ElseIf mydate4 - datetoday4 = 30 Then
                    EMail.To = Cells(x, 20).Value
                
                    'With EMail
                    .Subject = Cells(x, 19).Value
                    .Body = Cells(x, 19).Value
                    .Display
                    '.Send
                                
                    'Else
                End If
            End With
        
            Cells(x, 23) = "Yes"
            Cells(x, 23).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(x, 24).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2
        
            Cells(x, 27) = "True"
            Cells(x, 27).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(x, 28).Value = mydate4 - datetoday2
        End If
    Next
    Set EMail = Nothing
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```